# Javascript Library to generate excel files

Tags: javascript, excel, excellentexport

I'm looking for a library to generate excel files. It is not just about outputting csv, or some rows, but about a library which would also make easier to do some basic formatting like header rows, changing colors and font size.

There are many excel generation libraries for the server, but I cannot find anything more than some examples on how to write it myself. There is a library going in this direction:
https://jordiburgos.com/post/2017/excellentexport-javascript-export-to-excel-csv.html
But it's more for generating excel based on tables in HTML. And in addition, it doesn't cover more advanced topics like those I mentioned.

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&o=desc&q=excel&s=stars&type=Repositories